# Pass multiple variables in helm template

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm

Is there a way to pass multiple variables in `template` or a function using `include`? In my case I iterate over a list of items, but in the template I also need the `.Release.Name` variable.

Is there a way to add to `$client` the `.Release.Name`? I tried something like `{{ $client.Name := .Release.Name }}`, but it throws an error..

I have the following template:

```
{{- range $client := .Values.global.clients }}
{{- with $ }}
search.service-{{ $client.clientId }}.cfg: |
{{ include "rest-api.search" $client | indent 4}}
{{- end}}
{{- end}}
```

The rest-api.search function:

```
{{- define "rest-api.search" -}}
client.id={{ .clientId }}
id={{ .clientId }}
uri=http://{{ .Release.Name }}:11666/{index}/ws/{configuration}
default.index=quicksearch
default.configuration=form
query.sort=
query.filter=
query.dsf=word
query.lower=0
query.max=10
query.locale=de
query.query=*
# Index mapping
index.COMMON=quicksearch
index.REF=quicksearch
supportObjectGroup=true
# authorization scheme
authScheme=NONE

{{- end -}}
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: I moved the content of the file into the first template.. After trying different ways I gave up.. It would be nice to have a solution for that ..

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can pass client object alongside release object in a dict

**values.yaml**

```
global:
  clients:
    - name: test
      clientId: test-123
```

**configmap.yaml**

```
{{- range $client := .Values.global.clients }}
{{$data := dict "client" $client "release" $.Release }}
search.service-{{ .clientId }}.cfg: |
{{ include "mychart.search" $data | indent 4}}
{{- end}}
```

**_helpers.tpl**

```
{{- define "mychart.search" -}}
client.id={{ .client.clientId }}
id={{ .client.clientId }}
uri=http://{{ .release.Name }}:11666/{index}/ws/{configuration}
default.index=quicksearch
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: I looked exactly how to do that with dict, but couldn't find any examples. Thanks